# read files in a directory specified by a command line argument

Tags: python

I am trying to read files from a directory specified by a command line argument.The command line:

```
./printfiles.py ./test_dir
```

The code I have so far is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys

input_dir=argv[1]
for file in os.listdir(input_path):
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            print(line)
```

I am getting the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hello.txt'
```

I think that the problem is because os.listdir() only returns file names, not the path. I am confused as how to do this because the path is just specified by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think that the problem is because os.listdir() only returns file names, not the path.

I think you're correct.

You can give `open` the full path to the file by using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
with open(os.path.join(input_dir, file), "r") as f:
```